# Showing MGF of Poisson converges to MGF of N(0,1)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, poisson-distribution, asymptotics, moment-generating-function

I'm trying to finish up a proof of the CLT for the Poisson distribution, but am having some trouble evaluating a limit. I've shown that the moment generating function for the standardized Poisson is $$M_X (t) = \exp \left \{-t\sqrt{\lambda}-\lambda+\lambda e^{t/\sqrt{\lambda}} \right \}$$ (this is the form of the MGF which was asked for us to show) But I'm having some trouble evaluating $$\lim_{\lambda \rightarrow \infty} \exp \left \{-t\sqrt{\lambda}-\lambda+\lambda e^{t/\sqrt{\lambda}} \right \} = e^{t^2/2}$$ Any suggestions for my mathematically-challenged mind?

Comment: Please don't answer the question in the question - leave your question as a question and post your answer as an answer. (Then I can upvote both.)

Comment: Ah, okay then--I wasn't sure what the etiquette was for answering your own question. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: It's totally [permissible to answer your own question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer); indeed the wording there says 'explicitly encouraged'. If you edit your question to copy and paste your answer into the answer box, post that, and remove it from your question (if you do it via an edit you'll keep all the formatting). It's possible to have a question-edit and an answer-edit open simultaneously in the same window.

Comment: +1 now on both, thanks. (Among other things, this way all the search function features work as they should.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of my roommate. Here's the solution if anyone is curious:

$$
\begin{align*}
M_X (t) &= \exp \left \{-t\sqrt{\lambda}-\lambda+\lambda e^{t/\sqrt{\lambda}} \right \} \\
        &= \exp \left \{ -t\sqrt{\lambda}-\lambda \right \} \exp \left \{ \lambda e^{t/\sqrt{\lambda}} \right \} 
\end{align*}
$$

And by expanding the term $e^{t/\sqrt{\lambda}}$ by the Maclaurin series we have

$$
\begin{align*}
M_X (t) &= \exp \left \{ -t\sqrt{\lambda}-\lambda \right \} \exp \left \{ \lambda \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{(t/ \lambda)^i}{i!} \right \} \\ 
&= \exp \left \{ -t\sqrt{\lambda}-\lambda \right \} \exp \left \{ \lambda \left ( 1 + \frac{t}{\sqrt{\lambda}} + \frac{t^2}{2\lambda} + \frac{t^3}{6\lambda^{3/2}} + \cdots \right ) \right \} \\
&= \exp \left \{ -t\sqrt{\lambda}-\lambda \right \} \exp \left \{ \lambda + t\sqrt{\lambda} + \frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{t^3}{6 \sqrt{\lambda}} + \cdots  \right \} \\
&= \exp \left \{ \frac{t^2}{2} + \frac{t^3}{6 \sqrt{\lambda}} + \cdots  \right \} \rightarrow e^{t^2/2} \text{ as } \lambda \rightarrow \infty. 
\end{align*}
$$

Woot.