# Proof Poisson converges to Normal

Tags: mathematical-statistics, convergence, central-limit-theorem

I am looking for a formal proof that, with the CLT transformation, a random variable $Y \sim POI(\lambda)$ converges to a normal distribution ($Z\sim N(0,1)$).
I believe this can be formulated as:
$$lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{y_n - \lambda n}{\sqrt{ \lambda n}} \rightarrow N(0,1) $$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Showing MGF of Poisson converges to MGF of N(0,1)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/79003/showing-mgf-of-poisson-converges-to-mgf-of-n0-1)

Comment: What does "$y_n$" represent??  Evidently it's intended to be a sequence of random variables of mean and variance $\lambda n,$ perhaps related to your "$Y,$" but even then the sum diverges if the $y_n$ are independent.  Perhaps you will find the related question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/383620 helpful in formulating your question (and maybe even in answering it yourself).

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Try finding the limit of the characteristic function or moment generating function.

Or (if allowed) just apply the central limit theorem, as $Y_n$ has the same distribution as the sum of $n$ independent copies of $Y$